# Do I need a DNS in my domain to let my clients find the WSUS server?

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2012, domain, dns-hosting

I have my WSUS installed on the same system as my Active Directory management. The weird thing is, that when i put a client in the same domain, i find it in my AD but not on my wsus. The client searches to the wsus my: http://mywsus.mydomain:8530 . so cant my client find the wsus because the dns isnt installed in my domain? So can i fix the problem by downloading dns? Or even by changing the http://mywsus.mydomain:8530 to 192.168.0.100(ip of server):8530?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your AD server is a DNS server. It wouldn't work otherwise

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you say "Active Directory Management Server" you mean your Domain Controller? Microsoft explicitely disadvises from using WSUS on a Domain Controller. Did (or let's say tried) that once in 2008, didn't work at all and will never ever ever do it again ;-)

The other thing is that you should find some "wsus" entries in your DNS pointing to your WSUS-Server (aka itself).What system are you using at the moment? Just go to "start" type in "DNS" and you should find the DNS management.